# openssl x509:No filename or uri specified for loading certificate

Tags: ios, ssl, openssl, certificate

```
openssl x509 -inform DER -noout -subject <certificate
```

Error:
No filename or uri specified for loading certificate
Unable to load certificate

Comment: This exact line works perfectly for me. No idea what you are doing differently.

Comment: I found that it was the OpenSSL version that caused this, I used the alpha version(OpenSSL 3.0.0-alpha7-dev)

Comment: Changing to a stable version of OpenSSL solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that it was the OpenSSL version that caused this, I used the alpha version(OpenSSL 3.0.0-alpha7-dev)

Changing to a stable version of OpenSSL solved my problem.